# Converting tab-delimited text file with multiple columns to XML

Tags: java, c#, xml

I'm trying to programmatically convert a text file with multiple columns of info into an XML file with this format:

```
<ExampleDataSet>
<Example ExID="AA" exampleCode="AA" exampleDescription="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION"/>
<Example ExID="BB" exampleCode="BB" exampleDescription="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION"/>
<Example ExID="CC" exampleCode="CCC" exampleDescription="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION"/>
<Example ExID="DDD" exampleCode="DD" exampleDescription="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION"/>
<Example ExID="EEEE" exampleCode="EE" exampleDescription="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION"/>
</ExampleDataSet>
```

I've found other examples that do similar conversions, but on a simpler level. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why can't you parse the delimited file into an object, then write the object as an XML file?

Comment: I would do that if i knew how lol I'm a newbie

Comment: With which language?  You have `java` and `c#` both tagged.  Also you haven't shown much in terms of what you've attempted thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create an XML document using the below. This example creates an XML document with 1 element and the attributes required.

First, create the xml document itself and append the top level element collection header.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode node = doc.CreateElement("ExampleDataSet");
            doc.AppendChild(node);
```

Now create a new element row. ( you would need a loop here, 1 per csv row!)

```
            XmlNode eg1 = doc.CreateElement("Example");
```

Then create each of the attributes of the element and append.

```
            XmlAttribute att1 = doc.CreateAttribute("ExID");
            att1.Value = "AA";

            XmlAttribute att2 = doc.CreateAttribute("exampleCode");
            att2.Value = "AA";

            XmlAttribute att3 = doc.CreateAttribute("exampleDescription");
            att3.Value = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION";

            eg1.Attributes.Append(att3);
            eg1.Attributes.Append(att2);
            eg1.Attributes.Append(att1);
```

Finally, append to the parent node.

```
            node.AppendChild(eg1);
```

You can get the XML string like this if you need it.

```
            string xml = doc.OuterXml;
```

Or you can save it directly to a file.

```
            doc.Save("C:\\test.xml");
```

Hope that helps you on your way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you can write this as, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="columns" select="'exId', 'exCode', 'exDesc'"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <DatasSet>
    <xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text-lines('input.csv')">
      <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(., '\t')"/>
      <Example>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($tokens)">
          <xsl:attribute name="{$columns[$i]}" select="$tokens[$i]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Example>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </DataSet>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm not sure why you tagged the question "Java" and "C#" but you can run this using Saxon-HE called from Java or C# or from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq and assuming first row of the file are the column headers

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc.Add(new XElement("ExampleDataSet"));

            XElement root = doc.Root;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            int rowCount = 1;
            string line = "";
            string[] headers = null;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (rowCount++ == 1)
                {
                    headers = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] arrayStr = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    XElement newRow = new XElement("Example");
                    root.Add(newRow);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayStr.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        newRow.Add(new XAttribute(headers[i], arrayStr[i]));
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```